# Dysfunctionality in the use of calendars or diaries

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to describe someone who is dysfunctional in the use of calendars or diaries and often mixes up dates on schedules?

Comment: calendar impaired

Comment: "Chronological Dyslexia" is not one word, but is sometimes used to describe the condition in the question

Comment: There are several phrases for "always late" in a social sense, but they're not coming to me (mainly because they're always said before I arrive).

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple such words (and phrases), such as:

- ***Unreliable*** (short and sweet; and no excuses, just straight to the point)
- ***Flaky*** (colloquial synonym for *unreliable*)
- ***Scatter-brained*** (less specific to timekeeping, but common); basically synonymous with…
- ***Absent-minded*** (implies forgetfulness, lack of awareness; such people tend to miss appointments)

I can add links if threatened, but you should probably look them up :o)

Comment: -1 because I think what you're describing are adjectives for someone who has characteristics that would possibly lead to mixing up dates, or running late, or missing events, i.e. bad with time management, but that has nothing to do with actually being bad at using a calendar and schedule,